# Count div that are automatically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this code:

```
<body>
<div id="pages"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        function createDiv(divclass,text) { 
                $('<div/>', {
                    class: 'page' + divclass,
                    html: '<p>' + text + '</p>'
                }).appendTo('#pages');
            } 
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
                createDiv("",i);
            }
            var pagesdisplay = $('page').length;
            console.log(pagesdisplay);
        });
</script>
```

Output is:

```
<div class="page">
     <p>1</p>
</div>
<div class="page">
     <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="page">
     <p>3</p>
</div>
<div class="page"><p>4</p></div>
```

When I look into console it show me 0. How can I count div that are automatically generated by my function?

**Edit: I can increment pagedisplay in that for(pagedisplay++) but this is not what I want.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace:

```
$('page').length;
```

with:

```
$('.page').length;
```

You need to prefix the classname with a dot (`.`) when using a [`class selector`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). Otherwise `$('page')` is looking for a `<page>` element in your DOM which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: omg!! yes, how I could not see that missing dot?? Thx for quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo, you want the selector to say $('.page')